# Button change style after onPress with React Native

Tags: javascript, button, react-native, styles

For example i have 3 buttons with bordered line, when i press 2 of them, 2 of these button will change its style to a color filled button.

Should i use `<Button>` or `<TouchableHighlight>` or `<TouchableOpacity>` or others?

I need a sample code for this in React Native.

Comment: what do you mean by press two of them ? do you want to change the style of two buttons at the same time ?

Comment: yes  you are  right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ıt doesn't matter, you can use all of them i usually use this approach when i click the button i change the state of triggered component like that

default state:    `this.state = { styleIndex: 0 }`

```
<Button
   onPress={this.press}
   style={this.state.styleIndex === 0 ? styles.buttonStyle : styles.buttonStyleClicked}/>
```

Comment: so if the button is triggered i want it to concat a value to an array, and when i press the second time i want to remove the value from the array. Do you know how?

Comment: You have to change the state value when you press the button onPress function should be like that `press() {
if (this.state.styleIndex === 0) {
    this.setState({styleIndex: 1})
} else {
    this.setState({styleIndex: 0})
}}`